# How to access web layer(Controllers) from the DAO Layer?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I had to cancel the running queries. In my DAO I set the `Entity.session` in the `ServletContext` when I start the query and remove it when the query is finished. Then check in the `Controller` if the session is present in the `ServletContext`, if it is present then I cancel the query by calling the `session.cancelQuery()` from the session object in the `ServletContext`.

This was working fine in my dev environment, but in my pre-prod testing the entire code does not run inside the tomcat container. The web part runs in tomcat whereas the data layer runs a java application. hence I could not find the `ServletContext` in the DAO class and it gave me a `ClassNotFound` Exception

So I decoupled the web layer in the DAO. Now I set the `hibernate.session` in the controller itself when it calls the DAO `calculate()`. But this created a problem, now the session exists even if there are no calculations going on and in actual there are some post or precalculations. And my mechanism to cancel the query doesn't work.

So what I need is a way to access the `Controller` from the `DAO` to set the session. I could have used a static method in the Controller and then set the session from it but I think this is again not a good practice.

DAO initial Code:

```
public calculate(){
Session session = mEntityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
//pre possing                   
if(session != null)
{
    mContext.setAttribute(""+view.getId(), session);
}
List<Object[]> results = query.getResultList();
mContext.removeAttribute(""+view.getId());
//post processing
}
```

Decoupled DAO code:
The method getSession() is called from the controller before the calculate method is called in the controller. And then when the user requests a cancel from the UI the `cancel` method is called in the controller.

```
public Session getSession()
{
    Session session = mEntityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
    return session;
}

public calculate(){
//pre possing                   
List<Object[]> results = query.getResultList();
//post processing
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping
public WebServiceResponse cancel(HttpServletRequest request)
{
    if(mContext.getAttribute(id) != null)
        ((Session)mContext.getAttribute(id)).cancelQuery();
}
```

Comment: If you need to access an upper layer from a lower layer, there is something wrong with your architecture. Further I think the `Session` class is not clear, as there is an `HttpSession`, but I guess your class is something different.

Comment: Yes it is the `org.hibernate.Session` not the `HttpSession`.

Comment: @hotzst but are you sure about it as I have always heard that such a practice creates a coupling which should be avoided and is not good design wise.

Comment: It is hard to guess an answer without completely understanding the control flow. Where is the cancellation triggered? Where is it handled? What triggers the cancellation? What should happen?

Comment: @hotzst I have updated the question please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have convoluted control flow because you are not properly separating detection of a problem from handling the problem: you detect a problem in the data layer but need to handle it in the presentation layer.

Consider using exceptions. Have the data layer throw an exception when it detects a problem. The presentation layer can handle problems in the data layer by catching exceptions.

Comment: I think the main problem is that I have couples the Servlet object in the data layer, which I need to decouple without losing the functionality.

Comment: I updated the question with some relevant code and more info, please have a look.