# How to get ServletContext object in the data layer?

Tags: java, tomcat

My application runs as 2 separate parts, the web module runs in the tomcat container and the data layer runs as a separate java program in a different service and they interact using the database.

I want to access the `ServletContext` in the data layer, how can I do this?

When I simply use the `ServletContext` in the data layer it gives me an exception `NoClassDefFoundError`.

Comment: You should absolutely not do this, such coupling of web and database tier breaks fundamental principles in OO design. Use data transfer objects and some form of IPC between these two applications.

Comment: Java Virtual Machine is not able to find that particular class at runtime which was available during compile time.

Comment: @John Yes I am aware that this is a bad design, but I absolutely need the ServletContext in the DAO's, could you give me some pointers in ` data transfer objects and some form of IPC` ?

Comment: What do you need the servlet context for?

Comment: The final objective is to cancel a running query. I use the ServletContext to set the Hibernate session and then retrieve the session in the controller to cancelQuery.

Comment: It's not possible to pass `ServletContext` **or** the Hibernate `Session` from Tomcat to separate program. Not only is your design fundamentally flawed, you probably don't understand how flawed it is.

Comment: @Kayaman is there a way to set the Hibernate `Session` somewhere so that it could be accessed in the `Controller` ?

Comment: You have 2 JVMs if I understood you correctly. One for Tomcat and one for the data layer that runs separately. You could pass data between them, but "live" objects such as `Session` or `ServletContext` can't cross over.

Comment: @Kayaman Yes, this is the scenario. I was looking for this as this would enable me to call `Session.cancelQuery()` in the `Controller` and would cancel the running DB query. Can I achieve this in some other way?

Comment: Instead of trying to pass objects where they don't belong and in this case cannot go, you'll need to signal the "owner" of the object to perform the cancelling instead.

Comment: @Kayaman Could you be a little more specific, giving an example if possible for my use case. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35263691/how-to-access-web-layercontrollers-from-the-dao-layer) i have described the scenario.

Comment: There's nothing to be specific about. Instead of trying to pass the `Session`, you'll have to ask the tomcat side to perform the task. There are plenty of different ways to communicate between programs, although the one you're using (via database) is probably one of the worst solutions for trying to cancel the query. You could of course cancel the actual DB query directly, but it might be too cumbersome. I don't know your system, so try to think of something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I took @Kayaman's advice. And tried to limit the use of objects in their respective layers i.e. using context in the presentation layer and the Hibernate `Session` in the Data Access Layer.

I passed the call from the `Controller` to the DAO and store the needed objects in a global map in the DAO which were later called for further processiong. And finally returned the signals back to the Presentation layer.